# While Uploading the Excel sheet table to SQL server table $ is not uploading with numbers but upload with text only

Tags: sql-server, excel

i want to upload the excel sheets data to the sql sever 2008, all my data i.e numbers and Alphabets  from my excel sheet table are  going to upload in the Database table but $ sign is not going to upload there as i have to use a currency as a column, $sign going to upload with text data but not with numbers.....pls let me knw abt this problem

this is my code

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Data;
using System.Data.OleDb;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Xml;
using System.Configuration;
using System.IO;
using log4net.Config;
using log4net; 


namespace ExcelUpload
{
    class Program
    {
        static ILog log = LogManager.GetLogger(typeof(Program));

        //Variable declarations
        public static string strSqlConnection, strExcelDataQry, strSqlTable, strExcelFilePath, sexcelconnectionstring;
        public static int intRows;

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            #region GET PARAMS FROM CONFIG FILE
            strSqlConnection        = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["SQLConnection"].ToString();
            strExcelFilePath        = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ExcelFileName"].ToString(); 
            string[] sqlSheets      = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["Sheets"].Split(',');
            #endregion

            #region SET CONNECTIONS
            sexcelconnectionstring      = @"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" + strExcelFilePath + ";Extended Properties='Excel 12.0 xml;HDR=YES;'";
            SqlConnection Sqlconn       = new SqlConnection(strSqlConnection);
            SqlBulkCopy bulkcopy        = new SqlBulkCopy(strSqlConnection);
            OleDbConnection oledbconn   = new OleDbConnection(sexcelconnectionstring);
            #endregion

            XmlConfigurator.Configure();
            log4net.ThreadContext.Properties["Context"] = "ExcelUpload";            

            try
            {
                log.Info("Started Execution of ExcelUpload Process");
                foreach (string sqlSheetName in sqlSheets)
                {
                    #region GET PARAMS FROM CONFIG FILE BASED ON CURRENT SHEET
                    strExcelDataQry = "select " + ConfigurationManager.AppSettings[sqlSheetName + "ColumnNames"] + " from [" + sqlSheetName + "$]";
                    strSqlTable     = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings[sqlSheetName + "Table"];
                    intRows         = Convert.ToInt32(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings[sqlSheetName + "RowsToExclude"].ToString());
                    #endregion

                    #region TRUNCATE TABLE
                    SqlCommand SqlCommand = new SqlCommand("TRUNCATE TABLE " + strSqlTable, Sqlconn);
                    Sqlconn.Open();
                    SqlCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
                    Sqlconn.Close();
                    log.Info("Table " + strSqlTable + " Truncated Successfully");
                    #endregion

                    #region BULK COPY DATA 
                    log.Info("Started processing the sheet " + sqlSheetName); 
                    OleDbCommand oledbcmd = new OleDbCommand(strExcelDataQry, oledbconn);
                    oledbconn.Open();
                    DataSet ds = new DataSet();
                    using (OleDbDataAdapter adapter = new OleDbDataAdapter(oledbcmd))
                    {
                        adapter.Fill(ds);
                    }

                    for (int iRow = 0; iRow < intRows; iRow++)
                    {
                        ds.Tables[0].Rows[iRow].Delete();
                    }                    
                    ds.Tables[0].AcceptChanges();

                    foreach (DataRow dr in ds.Tables[0].Rows)
                    {
                        foreach (DataColumn col in ds.Tables[0].Columns)
                        {
                            if (col.DataType == typeof(System.String))
                            {

                                    dr[col] = dr[col].ToString().Trim();
                            }
                        }
                    }

                    bulkcopy.DestinationTableName = strSqlTable;
                    bulkcopy.WriteToServer(ds.Tables[0]);
                    oledbconn.Close();
                    log.Info("Sheet " + sqlSheetName + " successfully loaded to the table " + strSqlTable); 
                    #endregion
                }
                log.Info("ExcelUpload Process completed successfully");
            }
            catch (System.Exception ex)
            {
                log.Info("Error while processing :- " + ex.Message);
            }
            finally
            {
                Sqlconn.Close();
                oledbconn.Close();
            }

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: column formatting for that particular column in excel may be as number. Change it to text and then try. Even I had faced a similar issue.

Answer (score 0):

If you want the currency column as `Int` you cant insert the `$` symbols and `decimal` in it because defaultly integer datatype won't allow it.
So, to solve your problem make the curreny as `Varchar` and insert the data as something like `$100.00`
and while displaying it just show it.
And while doing calculations in front end remove the `$` symbol using `Contains` keyword
 and convert it into `Double` and do your calculations.
Hope it helps

Comment: my column datatype in sql is for this is Varchar only, but while taking value from from dataset it takes only integer value it wont take $ sign as its excel sheet's coloumn formating, so

Answer (score 0):

Ok try this link for storing the data from excel to gridview(just for an example), you just change your need.
I also tested with that code to store the data which contains `$` symbol in the cells and store it in the database also displaying the same `data from the database with $ symbols in the same cells`.
Have a look at it, it may be useful.

[Load Gridview from Excel](http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/593181/Load-GridView-from-Excel)

just change the code for your need.